# How do I refresh an access token Instagram when it has expired?

Tags: javascript, node.js, instagram, instagram-api

I use nodejs as a framework on the server side. I have successfully retrieved access_token data and used it.

> but suddenly when I tried to request API it was rejected and after replacing the access_token it work again.

so as stated by the Instagram: `Access tokens may expire at any time in the future.`

> how long access_tokens will be expire ?

**Here my API request**

```
export const getMediaRecent = (req,res)=>{
    axios.get(`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=${keys.instagram.access_token}`)
        .then(result=>{
            let imageInstagram = result.data.data.filter((d,i)=> i < 10).map(r=>{
                return{
                    images:r.images,
                    caption:r.caption,
                    link:r.link
                }


            });
            return res.status(200).json(imageInstagram);
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            return res.status(400).json(err);
        });

}
```

is there a way to refresh an access token when it has expired?

Comment: Read their api docs. They should have details there for the refresh token procedure. You can use an axios interceptor to monitor responses for expired token error and do refresh request then repeat original request when you get updated token

Comment: can u give me some example ?